# Web Scraping - Container Tracking from Searates Website to Excel

Tags: vba, web-scraping

As lacking of essential IT knowledge, I am looking for your kind help to make codes for getting data (final destination & ETA estimated time of arrival) from website tracking container numbers SEARATES (https://www.searates.com/container/tracking/) to Excel.

I have tried method of using GetElementbyID using IE Internet Explorer but this website browser is seems obsolete and useless.

This SERATES website offer API information but it is too complicated for me to understand.
I am enclosing container tracking list for your testing.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E0tuA4pYMDPZMgwjQC8dDs6w6BxqVdXK/view?usp=sharing

Hope someone could give me support on this project which is important for my job of logistics.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone? I am expecting your kind help on this issue. Thanks. Maybe some advices?

Answer (score 0):

How about recording a Macro, for starters.

```
Sub Macro1()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E0tuA4pYMDPZMgwjQC8dDs6w6BxqVdXK/view", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "view"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.Left = 201.25
    Application.Top = 93.25
End Sub
```

Notice, you have to be signed in. I don't have login creds for this link.

Comment: Hi @ash , it is not what I meant, I want to base on this list of container numbers, search them on websites and pull results for each container number to Excel file

Comment: I'm not sure what containers are. Do you mean that you want to loop through items in a list or array or whatever, and do web queries based on that? You certainty do that, but you may need to start with a simpler example and work your way up to more and more complex things.  Try to loop through a list of URLs and import some data from each. If you get that working, you should be able to do a lot of other things. Again, I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish here.